# How to get query params from protractor APIs

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing

I'm performing **E2E** testing on my **Angular 7** application where I have a test case where I am applying filters from UI and the filter are attached to URL of the as **query parameters**.

The URL generated will look like:

`http://localhost:4000/search?programme=1`

But when I'm using `browser.getCurrentUrl()` it is just returning `http://localhost:4000/search` **without** the query params.

Now I'm using `browser.getLocationAbsUrl()` but Protractor itself is throwing error it is **deprecated**.

```
it('Select GV filter and check params', () => {
    searchPage.selectOnePrgram();
    expect<any>(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toContain('program=1'); 
   // [11:53:11] W/protractor - `browser.getLocationAbsUrl()` is deprecated, please use `browser.getCurrentUrl` instead.

});
```

My question is how can I get the query params into my `.spec.ts` file?

**IS IT EVEN COMES IN THE E2E SCOPE OR IT SHOULD BE IN  UNIT TEST?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just manage the promise using `then()`, which you are getting from `browser.getCurrentUrl()`.

**Example Code:**

```
  browser.getCurrentUrl().then(
    (res) => {
      console.log(res);
      // response will includes the url with query params
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

use async / await instead of promise chaining. The following should work. getCurrentUrl returns a promise and needs to be resolved. Refer to https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.getCurrentUrl-

```
it('Select GV filter and check params', async () => {
await searchPage.selectOnePrgram();
let currentLoc = await browser.getCurrentUrl();
expect(currentLoc).toContain('program=1');
```

});